# Is it possible to share dropbox datastore with distinct users?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

From the documentation of the Dropbox [Android Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/android) it says that it is possible to share a Datastore with other accounts based on *Principals* and *Roles*.

But then it seems that (for non Dropbox-Business users) the only available Principal is `DbxPrincipal.PUBLIC` which sounds that I can either share a Datastore with nobody or share it with the whole public.

Is this really the case or am I missing something here? To my understanding it would make way more sense to be able to specify which users I want to share the Datastore with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. But note that only someone who knows the datastore ID can actually access the datastore, and datastore IDs are unguessable. It's up to your app to give the datastore ID to the specific users you want to have access.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Still it seems not very safe. On the other hand the 64 character IDs are way more secure than most users' passwords ...